# Outgoing call from twilio number to mobile phone using ASP.NET Core Web API and Angular app

Tags: angular, .net-core, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I have requirement where admin user can directly call on user's mobile phone. Frontend is developed in Angular app and I have to make backend API which helps to Angular to call Twilio API for Outbound call.

I have created all credentials in Twilio console, but I do not have any idea what APIs need to implement in .NET Core. I have used sample code from Twilio site, and able to make call from users mobile, but do not know what to do once user picked up the call.

By using this code, I'm able to receive call, but do not what APIs need Angular side which can established two way communication

```
string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var call = CallResource.Create(
        url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+14155551212"),
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661")
);

Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with two way communication? Do you want that a user of the Angular web app is able to be called / call someone?

Comment: Yes, I want a user of Angular web App is able to call staff user on their phone no. Only Angular Web app user will call, once staff user receive call on their phone and after picked up the call , Both user can communicate.

Comment: In this case, you probably want to get started with the Voice SDK, because otherwise you just initiate a call that executes the TwiML music you linked above. This sample code might help you getting started <https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node>

Comment: I have just go through the sample code you provided, my question is just how many APIs or what API , I need to Develop which required for JavaScript SDK to handle call functionality. how the Realtime communication handle ,will it handle by VOICE SDK or do i need to create any API for that?

Comment: The SDK handles the call functionalities for you.

Comment: So, It means there is no need of Backend API?

Comment: Well, Twilio is the backend that handles most of it. Your own backend needs to take care of some minimal parts (like issuing the access token for the frontend). But I think this becomes clearer once you run the code

Comment: I am Backend developer, I do not have any idea about node JS, Can you please explain what APIS I need to Develop in .NET core C# for token generation and voice call handling.  Is there any GitLab refence where i can get the reference.